# Is it possible to generalize this lmap

Tags: haskell, functor, category-theory

I would like to generalize the bifunctor `lmap` a bit.

`lmap` normally takes a function and maps it across the left functor in a bifunctor.

To start I generalize the idea of `Functor` to categories beyond `(->)` (this will help us eliminate the need for a `Bifunctor` class).

```
class Category cat where
  id  :: cat a a
  (.) :: cat b c -> cat a b -> cat a c

instance Category (->) where
  id x = x
  (f . g) a = f (g a)

class (Category s, Category t) => Functor s t f where
  map :: s a b -> t (f a) (f b)
```

I also am going to need a `Flip` so that I can make contravariant functors, and bifunctors.

```
newtype Flip p a b =
  Flip
   { unflip :: p b a
   }
```

Now I can write my `lmap` by lifting a regular `map` up into `Flip`:

```
lmap c = unflip . map c . Flip
```

This flips the bifunctor, applies the map and then flips it back.  The issue however now arises that `Flip` and `unflip` have rather restricted types.

```
Flip   :: p b a -> Flip p a b
unflip :: Flip p a b -> p b a
```

Which means when I get the type

```
lmap ::
  ( Functor s (->) (Flip p c)
  )
    => s a b -> p a c -> p b c
```

Here the `(->)` in `Flip` and `unflip` forces our functors to map into the `(->)` category.

Of course there is nothing inherent to these that makes `(->)` the only category of which `Flip` can be seen as a morphism, for example there are perfectly sensible definitions for

```
Flip :: Flip (->) (p a b) (Flip p b a)
Flip :: Monad m => Kleisli m (p a b) (Flip p b a)
Flip :: Monad m => Flip (Kleisli m) (p a b) (Flip p b a)
```

et cetera.  In fact for every instance of `Category` I can think of there is a clear any easy instance of `Flip`.  But I clearly can't build `Flip` out of `(.)` and `id` alone.

Thus I would really like to generalize `lmap` to

```
lmap ::
  ( Functor s t (Flip p c)
  )
    => s a b -> t (p a c) (p b c)
```

Which makes it look a lot more like `map`.

Is this possible?  Is there someway that this type can be realized or am I stuck with `(->)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts
            , MultiParamTypeClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}

import qualified Prelude
import Control.Category.Constrained.Prelude
import Control.Arrow.Constrained
import Data.Type.Coercion

newtype Flip p a b = Flip { unflip :: p b a }

lmap :: ( Functor (Flip p c) s t
        , EnhancedCat s Coercion, EnhancedCat t Coercion
        , Object s a, Object s b
        , Object t (p a c), Object t (p c b), Object t (p b c)
        , Object t (Flip p c b), Object t (Flip p c a) )
         => s a b -> t (p a c) (p b c)
lmap c = flout Flip . fmap c . follow Flip

instance Prelude.Functor (Flip (,) a) where
  fmap f (Flip (x,y)) = Flip (f x,y)

instance Prelude.Monad m
   => Functor (Flip (,) a) (Kleisli m (->)) (Kleisli m (->))  where
  fmap (Kleisli f) = Kleisli $ \(Flip (x,y)) -> do
          x' <- f x
          return $ Flip (x',y)


main :: IO ()
main = do
  print $ lmap (+1) (0,0)
  t' <- runKleisli (lmap $ Kleisli print) (10,20)
  print t'
  return ()
```

```
(1,0)
10
((),20)
```